# Django admin site - limit user content on user

Tags: python, django, django-admin

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Blog


admin.site.register(Blog)
```

I have figured out that Django admin serves my needs very well. The only thing I would like to limit is that Users could write/read/edit the Blog applications but for their own entries only.

If Alice posts a blog, she can read/write/edit only her posts and not the posts of Bob. Does Django allow anything like this in the admin site or do I need to develop my code?

Comment: You can ovverride queryset using get_queryset method on ModelAdmin [DjangoDocs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset)

Answer (score 1):

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Blog

@admin.register(Blog)
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj is not None and obj.created_by != request.user:
            return False
        return True

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj is not None and obj.created_by != request.user:
            return False
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

The ModelAdmin class has a method called get_queryset() where you can specify which objects someone will see.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Blog

@admin.register(Blog)
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        return queryset.filter(author=request.user)
```